# join table on itself as added columns mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table that is used to hold answers to questions. Each question can be answered at different time intervals. Here's the table structure I have:

```
entry_index | ques_idx | ques | ans_idx |    ans     | entry_time | usr_id
     1            1     ques1..   1        ans 1        14:00         usr1
     2            2     ques2..   4        ans 4        14:00         usr1
     3            1     ques1..   2        ans 2        13:00         usr1
     4            2     ques2..   3        ans 3        13:00         usr1
```

What I am attempting to do is display the questions with the answers and the entry times as a column. For example:

```
ques  |  14:00   |     13:00
ques1..  ans 1         ans 2 
ques2..  ans 4         ans 3
```

Would a join be appropriate for this? I am at a complete loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the maximum number of answers a question may have? Your two examples have two answers each, but are they potentially unlimited?

Comment: this smells of really de-normalized data (column 3 at least), I could be wrong

Comment: Potentially unlimited...but in reality probably no more than 20 entry times per question.

Comment: Drew, I agree. But its inherited...at this point I can't change the structure.

Comment: How many columns do you want the result of your query to have?

Comment: Hey Hanno,  The user may answer a question once, twice, n... The column number will be variable.

Comment: I do not think it's doable with a simple `query` and `join`. I think you have to use some kind of `procedure` to build and output the result. but if you want to output every question with its answers one at a time, then you can do it with a `join`.